# With command-line jgit, how to checkout a single file back to its git version?

Tags: jgit

For example jgit diff returns 1 changed file, I want to revert it back to the versioned version. In normal git I would just

```
$ git checkout path_to_file
```

I tried

```
$ jgit checkout origin/master -- path_to_file
```

but nothing changes, no error, no nothing and the file remains

**UPDATE**

I tried:

1. `$ jgit checkout origin/master -- path_to_file` - no change
2. `$ jgit checkout -- path_to_file` - no change
3. `$ jgit checkout path_to_file` - error: `error: pathspec path_to_file' did not match any file(s) known to git.`
4. `$ jgit clean` - wants to clean untracked files, not untracked changes
5. `$ jgit checkout -f origin/some_other_branch; $ jgit checkout -f origin/master` - hoping that this would squash the changes, but then simply the 2nd command fails because "changes would be overwritten"
6. ...and many more things I don't remember any more ofc :)

Comment: Your commands are slightly different. Does leaving out `origin/master` change anything?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann no :( I added to the post the stuff I tried. So far only solution I have is to manually tweak the file to not be different from repo. A bunch of lost time every time an enterprising sysadmin thinks "he'll just change this URL here in the config XML"

Comment: Is jgit supposed to completely replace git? Why can't you have both?

Comment: @hasen, I'm running this on an ancient version of Sun Solaris (yes, from before Oracle purchased it) - it's a wonder Java runs, but no way I have been able to get normal git there installed after years of pressuring the sysadmins with various carrots and sticks, it just will not happen

Comment: Perhaps a hard reset? I'm not sure it's in the CLI, but if you have Java and jgit there, you could, theoretically, write a tiny program to do just that.

Comment: @NimrodArgov yeah.... java is not really my forte :) but yeah, that will be the ultimate result if all else fails - either that or continue scp-ing key files to sync them with git when an enthusiastic sysadmin goes and edits files on his own :cripes:

Comment: @NimrodArgov what are the potential hazards of hard resetting?

Comment: @bbozo if you don't care about the file changes, there are no potential hazards. The reset basically does exactly that - changes all files back to the way they were in the commit. 
The Java code should basically be something like: 

`Git git = new Git(repo);
git.reset().setMode(ResetCommand.ResetType.HARD).setRef("HEAD").call();
`

Comment: @NimrodArgov, yeah... that's for sure more than I can do now <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just tried, and `jgit checkout -- path_to_file` works for me:

```
~/Development/Eclipse/jgit (master)

$ org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/target/jgit --version
jgit version 4.9.0-SNAPSHOT

$ org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/target/jgit status
On branch master

$ echo "dummy" > pom.xml

$ org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/target/jgit status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:

        modified:   pom.xml

$ org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/target/jgit checkout -- pom.xml

$ org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/target/jgit status
On branch master
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version of what, jgit? My post says it: `jgit version 4.9.0-SNAPSHOT` (built from yesterday's `master` branch).

Comment: FWIW, I also tried with the latest release `4.8.0.201706111038-r`, same thing, that also works for me. If it does for you, too, mind accepting the answer?

Comment: I'm super away from computers, but if it works for you it must work for me <3

Comment: It works ^_^ with 4.6. it didn't work, I upgraded to 4.9., works like a charm ^_^